# Kmers - How to join sequences and put substrings into array

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to find a way to implement a small bioinformatics library for operations with DNA sequences. These are represented as strings of only characters A, C, G and T. How do I make this method take the following parameters?

1. an integer specifying K
2. an arbitrary number of DNA sequences each provided as individual arguments

I need to make it so it joins these sequences and puts each one into its own array.

I have created two methods so far: Main() and Kmers(). I have made it so the Kmer method will break down a string such as "AGATCGAGTG" into 3-mers such as:

AGAGATATCTCGCGAGAGAGTGTG

My Main() method then prints these values:

```
using System;

class Sequence
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string kmerArray in Kmers(3, "GCATACGAT"))
        {
            Console.Write(kmerArray);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Array Kmers(int k, params string[] x)
    {
        int ArraySize = x.Length;
        string[] kmer = new string[ArraySize];

        for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize - k + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i <= ArraySize)
            {
                kmer[i] = x.Substring(i, k);
            }
        }

        return kmer;
    }
}
```

My output should look like this:

AGA,GAT,ATC,TCG,CGA,GAG,AGT,GTG

Comment: I also added a demo to my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` must be a `string` and not `string[]`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Kmers(int k, string x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length - k + 1; i++)
        yield return x.Substring(i, k);
}

string[] result = Kmers(3, "GCATACGAT").ToArray();
```

And if you need a comma separated string:

```
 string result = string.Join(",", Kmers(3, "GCATACGAT"));
```

To to it just using `System` namespace:

```
public static string[] Kmers(int k, string x)
{
    string[] result = new string[x.Length - k + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length - k + 1; i++)
        result[i] = x.Substring(i, k);
    return result;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZraoAo)

"**Edit** (Considering the comments):

If you are expecting an array of string as a parameter and should return an array comma separated strings the `Kmers` function should be like this:

```
public static string[] Kmers(int k, string[] x)
{
    string[] result = new string[x.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
    {
         string[] itemresult = new string[x[j].Length - k + 1];
         for (int i = 0; i < x[j].Length - k + 1; i++)
              itemresult[i] = x[j].Substring(i, k);
         result[j] = string.Join(",", itemresult);
     }
     return result;
}
```

and also you should pass `string[]` to it:

```
string[] input = {"GCATACGAT", "GACGAT", "ACGATCATA"};
string[] result = Kmers(3, input);

foreach (string x in result)
   Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Result:

> GCA,CAT,ATA,TAC,ACG,CGA,GAT
>
> GAC,ACG,CGA,GAT
>
> ACG,CGA,GAT,ATC,TCA,CAT,ATA

Comment: Hey this is fantastic! We are only allowed to use System though. Is there a way to execute the Kmer method by only using the parameters - public static Array Kmers(int k, params string[] x).

Its frustrating because I was initially using using System.Collections.Generic; but was told by my tutor not to. They have assured me that I need to declare params string[] x in the method signature.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a way that involves joining sequences instead of a string. Also, each output has to be an array.

This is the question:

This method, Kmers, must take the following parameters in the order specified:

an integer specifying k
an arbitrary number of DNA sequences each provided as individual arguments
In the form of a string array, this method must return all the k-mers contained in the assembled sequence x where x  is formed by concatenating all the provided DNA sequences in the order they are provided to the method.

Comment: you mean an array of arrays, `[['G','C,'A'],['C','A','T'],...]`?

Comment: in your example: `Kmers(3, "GCATACGAT")`, you get a string as a parameter, if you want to get an array of string, please tell me that what each item of array should be,.

Comment: Each item of the array should be the output that Kmers(3, "GCATACGAT") gives:

So each result would be

kmer[0] = "GCA"
kmer[1] = "CAT"
etc.....

Comment: then what is the output for it? an array of comma separated values for each item in input? `AGA,GAT,ATC,TCG,CGA,GAG,AGT,GTG`

Comment: Yeah the expected output should look like that. The tutor just said that it should output a String Array, not a string.

Comment: there was an error in my edited code. please have a look at it now.

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution:

```
string input = "AGATCGAGTG";
int k = 3;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length - k + 1).Select(x => input.Substring(x, k));
```

output result:

```
AGA
GAT
ATC
TCG
CGA
GAG
AGT
GTG
```

if you want to join with comma: you do the join with ","

```
string r = string.Join(",", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LINQ`

```
    IEnumerable<string> Substrings(string str, int size)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length - size + 1)
            .Select(i => str.Substring(i, size));
    }

    Console.Write(string.Join(",", Substrings("GCATACGAT", 3).ToList()));
```

output

```
GCA,CAT,ATA,TAC,ACG,CGA,GAT
```